# Is it possible to have a 'sticky' footer on a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build a checkout screen allowing the user to enter card details etc. I want to have 'buy with Apple Pay' or 'other' buttons pinned to the bottom of the `UITableViewController` so they are easily visible at all times.

I'm aware that this would be possible with a `UITableView` nested in a `UIViewController` but I'm just wondering if a similar result is possible using `UITableViewController`?

Here is a [screen recording](https://share.icloud.com/photos/0v65ZNtUGAUzX7eNzQGBcD2vg) of the Apple Store app showing the desired behaviour. (expires 18th August)

Answer (score 1):

You can use table view datasource method like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // Write your code for sticky design 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

It may helps you.Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue with this for me is that it is only at the bottom of the screen if the height of the section is greater than the available area. Ideally, I want it to stay at the bottom regardless.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for not using a `UITableViewController` and using a regular `UIViewController` with a table view added manually to it—this is one of them. Actually, the only real reason for a `UITableViewController` is when you want to have static cells instead of dynamic prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth moving the UITableViewController in to an embedded view. That way you can have whatever you like overlay the bottom of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

`tableFooterView` will only be visible after that last cell. Out of the box solution is not available for this issue. If you are adding section footer you will face two possible issues i.e if you have more than one section and when the content is less than the height of tableview. Only possible solution is adding a `UIView` above your tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a extra view on tableview controller ui view controller view. You have to get attention view hierarchy for that.